# File and bundleresource:// URLs

Tags: java, file, url, eclipse-rcp

I've been breaking my head over this for quite a while now and cant find a solution for this problem:

I have an Eclipse RCP application that uses a custom library packaged as jar. From the plugin, i am calling a method within the jar.
Within this method, i am "getting" a resource using `this.class.getResource(relPath)`, whereas `relPath` is a hardcoded relative path to a file i need. This returns me an `URL` which i can use to construct a `File`.

Now, this works perfectly if i am not calling this method from the plugin, but from a simple Java-Program.
The difference: Eclipse RCP's classloader returns an `URL` of protocol `bundleresource://` which is not supported by `File`, whereas when running a simple Java-program, a `file://`-URL is returned which is completely fine to construct a `File`.

I am aware of the `FileLocator`-class of the Eclipse SDK (which resolves bundleresource-URLs to file-URLs), but i cannot use it within the library because i dont want to tie it to the Eclipse RCP platform - it should be possible to use this lib from non-Eclipse-RCP sources as well.

Anyone any idea on how i can load this resource from a relative path in a manner that will work both when the method is called from an Eclipse RCP-Plugin or any other client?

I need to construct a `File` on the directory of this relative path to search for files within. I am completely stuck on this...

**UPDATE**: If there is a possibility other than using [File#list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) to get directory contents this would already help me..

any hints greatly appreciated,

Comment: Can you list the relevant code?

Comment: @TonnyMadsen Hm, i could but basically its very simple: I am using this.getClass().getResource(relPath) to load a path within my classPath. This returns me a bundleresource:// URL when done under Eclipse RCP and a file:// URL otherwise.
Trying to create a File-Object fails with the bundleresource:// URL because File does not support this protocol.
Since i need to read the directory contents of "relPath" i am forced to use a File...

Comment: How do you convert the URL to a File?

Comment: @TonnyMadsen new File(url.toURI())

Comment: In this case, it only works for file:// URLs... There are plugable API to convert an URL to a Stream, ut not to a File. Also noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843557/uri-scheme-is-not-file

Comment: @TonnyMadsen Yes i know, this is exactly my problem :) Thats why i was interested how others handle this problem, i guess there are ppl who already encountered this (loading resources using the Eclipse Classloader and in need of File-References)..

Comment: The only solution I can come up with, is to use reflection to access `FileLocator` and convert the URIL to a `file://` based version...

Comment: @TonnyMadsen Unfort. that's a no-go. I cant have references to Eclipse-Core classes in my library. Anyways - i appreciate your thoughts, thanks!

Comment: You can do this by just having String references. Like `Class.forName("org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator")` to get the `FileLocator` class and `class.getMethod("resolve")` to get the method...

Comment: @TonnyMadsen: Yes but what i meant is: I then need to bundle the FileLocator-Class (and all its dependencies) with my library so that it still works when there is no Eclipse involved (i.e. it is being used in a Web-App)

Comment: Hmm.. not sure what you mean. I would add a proper `MANIFEST.MF` file with an optional requirement for `org.eclipse.core.runtime`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Couldn't you simply invert the dependency. I.e., your module retrieving the resource as URL defines an interface

```
interface Locator { URL resolve(URL url); }
```

and you can use a default implementation

```
class StandaloneLocator implements Locator {
   public URL resolve(URL url) { return url; }
}
```

In case of Eclipse, this default locator is to be replaced by

```
class EclipseLocator implements Locator {
  public URL resolve(URL url) { return FileLocator.resolve(url); }
}
```

Now, your library has no dependencies to Eclipse, and you can still use the FileLocator. Since you won't get any bundleresource-URLs w/o Eclipse, this should work.

Cheers,
Jens

Comment: I already circumvented the problem itself before you answered, but this is a really good idea! Appreciate it and might refactor it in next time :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to enumerate files in jar file using methods from `Class`. You either need to create `resourcelist` file which will contain all your resources names, or open jar file like zip archive and enumerate files like in zip archive. `File` class can not handle protocols other than `file://`. If your rescource is in jar file, you should use `Url` class and get stream using `Url.openSteram` method to get file contents.

**UPD** regarding running simple java application: you probably does not pack it into jar file, so your classes and resources are placed in file system and not in archive. That is why you get `file://` protocol. If you pack into jar file, protocol will not be `file://` it will be `jar://` (not sure about exact protocol name).

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but the file/resource is not in a jar, but in a dir within the classpath of the application.
Concerning Url.openStream(): Its unfortunately not possible to read directory-contents using this method (i need to load a directory as resource and check for existing files).